# Adding text on specific line on listbox/listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

Is it possible to insert a new item to a listbox at a specific line?
I already tried `litsbox1.Items.Add()` but this method did not accept any index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try
`listBox1.Items.Insert(desiredIndex, yourObject);`

Hope this is what you want..